# When Ignite allocated next memory segment?

Tags: ignite

I use embedded apache ignite in spring.
Once I test stress test, TPS is temporarily drop down when appearing below log.

```
a.i.i.p.impl.PageMemoryNoStoreImpl : Allocted next memory segment [plcName=default, chunkSize=422.2MB
```

I guess the memory configuration is needed.
so I configure systemCacheMaxSize and systemCacheInitialSize, but not changed

My application is need stable tps guarantee.

How can I fix it?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved It.

I needed `MemoryPolicyConfiguration`.

Here are my solutions.

```
new MemoryConfiguration()
    .setMemoryPolicies(new MemoryPolicyConfiguration()
        .setInitialSize(initSizeMb * 1024L * 1024)
        .setMaxSize(maxSizeMb * 1024L * 1024L))
```